# How to calculate hash of a python class object

Tags: python, oop, hash, md5

In python3, I have a class. Like below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3
    def fcn(self, val):
        self.x += val
```

Then I instantiate objects of that class, like so:

```
new_obj = Foo()
new_obj2 = Foo()
```

Now when I hash these objects, I get *different hash values*. I need them to return the same hash, as they are the same objects (in theory).

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You are free to implement `__hash__` if you'd like. However I question your intent, as *"they are the same objects"* is not true in most definitions that come to mind. Perhaps you believe the objects should be *equal* to each other?

Comment: They are not, not in theory and not in practice.

Comment: See my answer as to these being the same object.  That said, what characteristics do you expect your `hash` function to exhibit?  What are the `Foo` properties that you want to embody in that function?  To put it another way, if you find that `hash(a) == hash(b)`, what do you want to have guaranteed about the objects `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Prune: Considering hash collisions, it may be more useful to instead determine what `hash(a) != hash(b)` should guarantee about `a` and `b`.

Comment: @user2357112: I realize that -- but I hope that the equality issue will focus OP on what is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3
    def fcn(self, val):
        self.x += val
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)
```

This will calculate the hash using `self.x`; That means the hash will be the same when `self.x` is the same. You can return anything from `__hash__`, but to prevent consistency bugs you should return the same hash if the objects compare equal. More about that [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to all who answered. You're right that instantiating a new instance of the same class object is not *actually* the same, as it occupies a different place in memory. What I ended up doing is similar to what @nosklo suggested.

I created a 'get_hashables' function that returned a dictionary with all the properties of the class that would constitute a unique class object, like so:

```
def get_hashables(self):
    return {'data': self.data, 'result': self.result}
```

Then my main method would take these 'hashable' variables, and hash them to produce the hash itself.

Answer (score 1):

They are *not* the same object.  The expression `Foo()` invokes the class constructor, `Foo.__init__`, which returns a *new, unique* instance of the object on each call.  Your two calls return two independent objects, residing in different memory locations, each containing its own, private instance of the `x` attribute.

You might want to read up on Python class and instance theory.